Terminal session "Powershell Extension" never fully loads
The terminal session "PowerShell Extension" never finishes loading to a prompt. The chasing circles just endlessly spin. I've tried doing a reset of all settings in VSCode but that has not resolved the issue of never getting to a prompt. I have not succeeded in finding where in settings this list of terminals is defined. I would just eliminate it from the startup of VSCode if I could.

I tried resetting all settings in VSCode and it had no effect.

Figured it out. There was a problem with one of the paths in my environment varible PSModulePath. I removed the problem path and terminal console loaded to a prompt.
